Apps Script - Achieving Different (multiple) Locks on Different Parts of Script

There are two sheets for data storage: sheetA and sheetB.
Two forms: formA and formB. formA has data for both sheets, formB - only for sheetB.
Two functions, functionAB and functionB for put data to sheetA+sheetB and to sheetB.

What behaviour is expected?
If user repeatedly calls functionAB from formA, only first call will work, and both functions will be used (as they are chained).
If user repeatedly calls functionB from formB, only first call will work.
(Other way to say: both functions have to be locked when used directly, but second one has not to be locked when using in a chain).
This behaviour do works in my code. But realization uses userLock once and scriptLock second time.
It is not ideal, because:

limits use to 3 functions ('script', 'user', and 'doc' locks),
we need to always remember where and which types of locks are used.

Is it possible to make different lock flags of one type? Like 'lock1', 'lock2', etc.
(Using some kind of global or properties var is not so good, because, they cannot auto-erase themselves in a case of error happened).
 const lockScript = LockService.getScriptLock() 
  lockScript.tryLock(0) // trying to lock which checks this is valid call
  if (!lockScript.hasLock()) { // if cannot lock, invalid
    // do some cancelling actions in case of too early call
    return 
  }
  // do useful staff, put data to sheetA
  functionB(partOfFormAdataForSheetB) // also put some data to sheetB
}
functionB (dataForSheetBFromFormBOrPartiallyFormA) { // put data from formA or formB to sheetB
               // can be run directly from formB, or as helper from formA (formA fills both sheets)
 const lockUser = LockService.getUserLock() 
  lockUser.tryLock(0) // trying to lock which checks this is valid call
  if (!lockUser.hasLock()) { // if cannot lock, invalid
    // do some cancelling actions in case of too early call
    return 
  }
  // do useful staff, put data on a sheetB
}

For those, who doesn't remember lock's logic well:
(description in docs are not great).
So, if I understand correct:
'locking' in fact, does nothing, but creates a flag. So we need to check this flag when necessary. Main difference with any kind of global var is about this "lock" flag always drops when function stops.
ADDED: As for Apps Script - Achieving Multiple Locks on Different Parts of Script question, it has nothing common with mine. Except the similar title, which in fact is wrong in the linked question (Problem there was not about single/multiple locks, but about same lock which was applied wrong way).
Still, @Renounce4's answer there is interesting, as pointing to the named lock library, https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/using-named-locks-with-google-apps-scripts/
It could be a great solution, and possible can be used. But description points only on timed locks, which are released only on time or succesful finish. While a critical feature of the Lock Service - releasing lock on an error is not mentioned.
If somebody uses this library and can confirm this feature is present, please report. (didn't find a discussion with the library to ask).

I think the question Apps Script: Achieving Multiple Locks on Different Parts of Script is similar to what you're looking for.

This question is similar to: Apps Script - Achieving Multiple Locks on Different Parts of Script. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JatsPPG , @ doubleunary - Answered in the Question (added part)

May be you can consider to fill a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113

Is it possible to make different lock flags of one type? - It seems that what you wanted is not designed for Lock Service. Just like @jpp said, you may consider filling out a feature request, as that's the best way to tell Google about these kinds of things.

Thanks @ jpp, @Jats PPG. I shell know, it has not been realized for a moment. It is not so vital for me, and I have this not-a-beatiful solution with up to 3 types of lock. Also there is this possibility of using library or direct cash service. Not so good, as it switches off on error case only by timer, but anyway.
